# Is it possible to force-build a complete DFA cache for an ANTLR4 grammar?

Tags: c++, antlr4

I'm looking into porting a JavaScript grammar that uses the C++ runtime from ANTLR3 to ANTLR4 (well technically the ANTLR3 version uses the C runtime, but that's not relevant right now).

The main issue I'm struggling with is performance. I have several performance issues that prevent me from getting even close to 0 overhead, but I'm going to focus on the most serious one in this thread: it seems to be incredibly hard to build a complete cached DFA, and parsing files that hit uncached transitions is incredibly slow.

I created a small test suite of 16 files and split warmup and test phases. (Antlr3 doesn't really need warmup but whatever)

When warmup set === test set (16 files each)

```
Test            ms
------------------
Antlr3Warmup   338 
Antlr4Warmup 55860  
Antlr3Test     335 
Antlr4Test     439
```

Looks close right? Now let's see what happens if the sets are disjoint (8 files each)

```
Test            ms
------------------
Antlr3Warmup    78  
Antlr4Warmup 32032  
Antlr3Test     273  
Antlr4Test   24356
```

Clearly, in 32 seconds it didn't even get close to building the DFA -- we just built enough to have good performance on identical files. I could try to add more files to the warmup suite, but performance never seems to improve, and it takes ~15m to go through a bigger warmup suite (e.g. jquery + angular + react). Profiling execution shows that indeed the bottleneck is `ParserATNSimulator::computeTargetState`.

What is happening? Is there a smarter way to build a complete DFA cache? E.g. `Parser::buildCompleteDFA()`.

For some context, I started from https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/javascript/JavaScriptParser.g4 and refactored the singleExpression rule to make the entire grammar SLL (before that, performance seemed to be even worse).

Edit: Ivan suggested the left-recursive refactoring might be to blame. So here's the same benchmarks without the refactoring (grammar is now LL):

When warmup set === test set (16 files each)

```
Benchmark      ms
--------------------
Antlr3Warmup  337  
Antlr4Warmup 4224
Antlr3Test    311
Antlr4Test   1785
```

ANTLR4 lost the edge on fully-cached files, but performance on non-cached files has improved. Will it help in the long run after the DFA cache has been built?

```
Benchmark      ms (same as before) ms (extra warmup)
--------------------
Antlr3Warmup                    77                77  
Antlr4Warmup                   455             47649
Antlr3Test                     275               274
Antlr4Test                    3750              3559
```

Not that much. I bet that longer and longer warmups would improve the performance, but that 1785 figure from the previous test is the lower bound.

Edit 2: Here is some profiling data about why the lower bound is so high:

```
Time spent w/ ATN transition logic: 12%
Time spent accessing the DFA:       16%
Time spent w/ shared_ptr:           27%
Time spent w/ dynamic_casts:        33%
```

(this is already after I've already removed some dynamic_casts. These are all downcasts actually, but I guess LLVM cannot optimize this well)

Plus, I still see calls to `computeReachSet` even for the same file being run twice! In the SLL grammar, the parser `adaptivePredict` would only call `getExistingTargetState`

Comment: Could you please show how did you make JavaScript grammar entire SLL?

Comment: By refactoring the left-recursive singleExpression rule into a list of "cascading" rules, largely copying and pasting from https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v3/blob/master/ECMAScript/JavaScript.g#L197 (plus of course setting `setPredictionMode(PredictionMode::SLL);`

Comment: And just to be clear, the results from the "Antlr3Warmup" benchmark are done using the same ANTLR3 grammar where I took the rules to refactor singleExpression.

Comment: I don't think that transforming left-recursion to common rules is a good idea. The performance will be bad for some cases.

Comment: My benchmark code was pretty raw when I made that change, but it did improve performance. Let me try the new benchmarks with the old LL left-recursive grammar.

Comment: I've edited the post with the data from your grammar.

Comment: Did you try Java or optimized C# runtimes?

Comment: No, the whole point is to end up with a C++ parser :-) I'm sure your grammar is not at fault, this seems to be most about a) the DFA cache not being as general-purpose as it intuitively should be b) lots of overhead due to dynamic casting and shared pointers (probably from translating the Java implementation, where there's nothing to optimize on this front).

Comment: @IvanKochurkin it doesn't matter if you use left recursive rules or unroll them. Internally ANTLR4 converts them to non-left recursive rules anyway. Hence, there's no impact on performance by either variant.

Comment: I just proved that it's not the case! I'm guessing ANTLR4 implicitly unrolls them at runtime while building the DFA, which makes the matching algorithm harder. On the other hand, unrolling them manually to generate an SLL grammar leads to more decisions, which leads to more DFAs, which leads to a harder time caching the target states. Either approach is slower than ANTLR3.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?